# Filtering Choice field in django model Form based on F.K relation

Tags: django, django-forms

Here is my sample model in model.py:

```js
class Division(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    ......
class Place(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    division = models.ForeignKey(Division, related_name='places')
    .....
class Story(models.Model):
    story_division = models.ForeignKey(Division)
    story_page = models.ForeignKey(Place) 
    ......
```

And in my forms.py :

```js
class storyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('story_division','story_page'...)
        ......
```

Now my storyForm shows two choice field, Division and Place, what i want is to dynamically filter from the dropdown list where places are related to its above division choice. How do i do that ?

Comment: I use Django select2 which lets you populate dropdowns using views. When the dropdown sets a cookie and requests new values for the second dropdown. It can then filter off the cookie.

You can also just post your form in JavaScript and instead of processing it return a list of values that you make <option> tags out of.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that django offers this out of the box. Didn't try Django select2 but I normally do this sort of thing with an ajax call.

So for your example: Every time the story_division change, you should call a view that will populate the story_page combo.